# IP Fragmentation: It's still the norm, right?

Tags: node.js, networking, udp, ip-fragmentation

Ever since I did sockets programming on a PDP/11, it's been the case that IP fragmentation will take care of the case where an IP datagram (such as a UDP datagram) is larger than the MTU for the segment allows.

Thus, I can send a UDP datagram of size 30 kB, and it might fragment to 20 segments of 1.5 kB on Ethernet, and then fragment each into three segments of <576 bytes later on for some particular wireless link, and as long as all the fragments make it to the other end, the UDP datagram makes it to the other end.

Then, I came across the documentation for the UDP socket in node.js, which claims that routers will drop datagrams that do not fit the MTU of the next segment. I thought this was only the case for datagrams with the "don't fragment" bit set in the header, but given that node.js is supposed to be a high quality product with some credibility in network circles, I'm wondering whether I missed something and  many routers will now treat all datagrams as if they are "don't fragment?"

Here's the link:
http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_buf_offset_length_port_address_callback

Here's the quote:

```
generally sending a datagram greater than the (receiver) MTU 
won't work (the packet gets silently dropped, without informing 
the source that the data did not reach its intended recipient).
```

So, did I miss something, or does the node.js documentation need an update?

Comment: I know routers don't *have* to accept fragments past a certain point, and any node along the way that says "nu-uh" can conceivably stop delivery.  The doc quote might just be a more-strongly-worded version of that...?

Comment: There's gotta be actual measurements of this somewhere, right? Just like we can get measurements of latency between continents, quality of various backbones, penetration of IPv6, etc...

Comment: Part of the point of UDP is that it's not based on connections, acknowledgements, etc etc.  That makes it better for some use cases, but also leads to situations like this.  You could use [Path MTU discovery](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1191) to figure out the largest datagram you can send without fragmenting.  Or, just stick with the IPv4 minimum of 576 bytes.  (Datagrams smaller than that will only be fragmented if the next hop requires it, and routers are supposed to be able to reassemble them.)

Comment: Also keep in mind, any missing fragment will cause the whole datagram to be tossed, and the receiver will never be notified of your attempt.  (Whether you get notified, seems a bit iffy.)  You should probably send a little at a time anyway, if only to minimize the amount of stuff you need to retransmit if something goes wrong.

Comment: I'm familiar with the strengths and weaknesses of IP fragmentation, thanks. My question was one of actual, observed, practice on the Internet, and whether something's changed in the last few years or not. Ideally, a link to some place that summarizes data about this that someone trusts :-)

Comment: It's not a "last few years" thing.  It's been that way for as long as i can remember.  (Granted, i wasn't playing around with PDP-11s.  :P But since the mid 90s, at least.)  Fragmentation is (and has always been) a pretty heavy burden on routers, so a decently configured router only does it when absolutely necessary.  It was never meant to be a replacement for proper behavior by a client app or the transport layer.

Comment: "node.js is supposed to be a high quality product with some credibility in network circles". Hardly. You will find all sorts of statements in libraries that don't agree with the TCP/IP RFCs. You should consider the latter as your only normative references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the answer is a little more nuanced.
Fragmentation is still a part of IPv4, and is largely supported by the Internet at large.
IPv6 removes fragmentation, and instead defers to the application to do MTU discovery.
Thus, the documentation note that made me question my assumptions is not so much "wrong," as it is "living in the future where somehow, most people have switched to IPv6."

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct with respect to IPv4. Over here they might be talking about receiver MTU ie. MTU of the receiving end of the link. MTU can be configured per port. A link is a connection between two port. For eg. in ethernet you can have a misconfigured LAN like this

PORT-A(mtu 1000) <----------> PORT-B(mtu 800)

In this case the sender(port A) will think the MTU of the link must be matching the MTU configured on it and hence will send packet of size 1000 bytes. When port B receives the packet, it will most probably drop it since it is greater than the MTU configured on that port.

Comment: Yeah, that's a mis-configured network. I don't worry too much about those -- I worry about standard practice among the internet backbone carriers and major ISPs.